# Webjobs sdk rest

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage

I see that Azure made webjobs sdk for .net plaform and what i like the most is the ability to get notified when new objects appear in blob/queue.

I've googled a lot and wasn't able to find the specific function in blob api, and since webjobs sdk is .net only i'm unable to use it.

Is this is possible to do that with rest calls, or is this .net function only?

Comment: Open up Fiddler and see what REST calls the .net SDK uses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The SDK is currently Alpha, which only has support for .NET. The blob monitoring code is writing in C# but making regular REST APIs to storage.  You could use the SDK as a blob listening service and have it make Web requests when new blobs are detected, ie:

```
// Helper to convert from blob inputs to web requests
public static void ListenForBlobs(
    [BlobInput(@"container/{name}")] Stream inputStream,
    string name // captured from [BlobInput]
    )
{
    // Make a web request (or other notification) notifying that container/name is now availabe.

}
```